# Windows 8 store app ListView detect when item finished loading

Tags: javascript, windows, listview, windows-8, event-handling

In a Windows 8 store app I bind a `listView` control to a `json` file that is loaded via `WinJS.xhr` and contains objects with image urls and descriptions. I want to be notified when the items of the `listView` have finished loading their respective images, but haven't found a corrosponding event.
The reference gives me the `ListView.onloadingstatechanged event` but that fires soon as the `ListView` has finished rendering the items on screen even if their images aren't loaded jet.

Please bear with me since I'm kind of new to programming with JavaScript, any hint is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance, 
Thomas